# How to reference Twig form values from within controller action?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a form and a hidden action that successfully runs the controller action.  I now want to include 2 variables (form input values) and then use those values while I am in the controller action.  How do I grab the value (theemailaddress) that was in the form?

Twig template file:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="psychEmail/publication/pubRequest">
        <input type="text" name="theemailaddress" value="" size="100">

        <!-- ...-->

        <input class="btn submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'Submit'|t }}">
    </form>
```

function IN controller:

```
public function actionPubRequest()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();

    $email = new EmailModel();
    $email->fromEmail = 'email@school.edu';
    $email->toEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $email->subject = 'Publication Request';
    $email->body    = 'Your requested publication is attached.';

    craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`craft()->request->getPost('name')`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getPost-detail) to grab any posted values from your form submission.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Craft 3**, then use [getParam()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-twig-variables-request.html#method-getparam) at your controller action:

```
$request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
```

with this you get all the posted data with one request, then you use what you need like this:

```
$name= $request->getParam("formInput");
```

where **"formInput"** is the input field name attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="formInput">
```